# Debugger not working in visual studio code It gets stuck on the line below

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, server, vscode-debugger

```
Listening to the dt_socket transport at address: 61032
```

[image: 1]

Error deployment in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

> Listening to the dt_socket transport at address: 61032

The error message indicates that the debugger is trying to listen for connections on port 61032 and fails.

It could be that the port is being used by another process. You can try changing the debug port number. Another possibility is that a firewall or network configuration is preventing the debugger from listening on the port. Or try restarting the debugger or vscode and make sure you have the latest version of the debugger installed.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem and it currently occurs because the new Visual Code update required JDK 17 and for some reason the Debbug mode did not work for me using a Maven project in java.

Comment: Hi Diego Fernando Rodrguez Gonzle, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)